# ssh login fails when character \ present in username

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have setup openSSH server in my workstation running windows 10 with username domain\user. But when I try to ssh into my system from my home mac I get an error 'Connection reset by port 22'.

As the username contains escape character(), I tried using these combinations 
1. ssh domain\username@ip 
2. ssh 'domain\username'@ip 
3. specified username in ~/.ssh/config file

Comment: Did you test it using a GUI client to check if it is a problem on client-side (passing the backslash correctly to `ssh`) or server-side (correct format of the username for the server)?

Comment: don’t understand why does this have downvotes. I’m struggling with exactly the same thing

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the escape character, you have to type "\\" (i.e. the escape character twice)

Comment: tried using  ssh domain\\user@172.26.90.87...getting error domain\\user@172.26.90.87's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: You might want to check out this question: https://superuser.com/questions/543626/ssh-permission-denied-on-correct-password-authentication